# Convert Array of String to timestamp, in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I Have an array which is displaying the time values as a string. So What I need is that I want to convert the string values to timestamp values so that I can use these values to create a chart.

for example I have values in the array format as following :

```
["2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32"]
```

So my question is that how can I covert the above array string values into a timestamp

Comment: You can simply create new Date object and pass in the string in that array one by one using a for loop. Like new Date(x); create a new array and put these date objects in that new array.

Comment: Do you want to convert it to the epoch timestamp? If so you can use `const res = arr.map(x => +new Date(x));`

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array and convert them to date using `new Date()`

```js
var a = ["2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32"];
a.forEach((e) => {
  var date = new Date(e);
  console.log(date)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and convert the string to a date object.

```
var dates = ["2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32"];
for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
    dates[i] = new Date(dates[i]);
}
```